# Questions about Fallout New Vegas damage calculations

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

1. How do limb damage multipliers interact when using limb damage multiplier unarmed weapon ( Fist of Rawr ) and using the cross attack in VATS that has limb multiplier too?
   Fist of Rawr is 2x limb and cross attack is 2.5x. What is the end result limb multiplier?
2. Do critical hits ignore armor?
3. Does melee/unarmed sneak attack multiplier add to VATS melee/unarmed multiplier?
   Melee and unarmed do 2x damage in VATS and sneak attacks do 2x damage, what if I do melee sneak attack while inside VATS? Will it do 4x damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I guess the modifier is supposed to be 2 x 2.5 = 5

AFAIK, limb damage only moidfies how quickly limbs get crippled, not the damage to the enemy's health pool. Note also, that you can't target limbs in VATS with unarmed/melee

2. Critical hits do not ignore armor. Critical damage adds the static critical damage, which is defined for each weapon individually (usually 1x base damage)
3. Disregarding perks, target armor, chems etc., the damage calculates as follows:

> ((Damage x Power + Unarmed Bonus) x Special + Critical Damage) x Sneak attack modifier

Power = 2 in case of Power attack/VATS attack

Sneak attack modifier = 5 for melee/unarmed

Unarmed Bonus = (Unarmed skill / 20) + 0.5

Special attack damage bonus = 1.10 for Cross attack

Critical damage = 75 for Fist of Rawr

More [here](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_combat#Combat_damage)